# How to Reset Sequences in Postgres After Migration Using DMS

Tags: postgresql, sequence

I am in the process of migrating a postgres database from premises to aws using DMS. I have about 100 tables all with sequences. Post migration, an insert on the target tables in AWS will fail as we need to reset the sequences. For example I reset some of the tables like this:
`select coalesce(max(pickuphourid), 0) + 1 from habit.dermographic;

alter sequence habit.dermographic_pickuphourid_seq restart with 5950;

select coalesce(max(weightid), 0) + 1 from habit.weight;

alter sequence habit.weight_weightid_seq restart with 60107;`

This is efficient if I have just a couple of tables with sequences. However with close to a 100 tables with sequences, it is inefficient and time consuming to look up each time and reset the sequences individually. I am looking to see if there is an efficient way for me to do this. thanks

Comment: That would seem to be either: 1) A bug in DMS or  2) You missed a step in the setup. In any case this is really an AWS support question, that should be directed at them.